# Cordova 3.6: how can I extract GPS Exif data from photo library in Android?

Tags: android, angularjs, image, cordova, exif

I'm developing an app with Cordova 3.6.x with Angularjs. Everything seems to work fine except the fact I can't extract date and location from the exif datas of an image taken from the photo library.

My target device is Android 4+

Since now I tested:
- https://github.com/lorinbeer/cordova-exif-utility ( no android support :( )
- https://github.com/guilhermefarias/cordova-exif (returns errors such "processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined" and "processMessage failed: Message: S01 File1189144150")
- https://github.com/kamilersz/cordova-plugin-exif (couldn't understand how it works)

On the net I read that Cordova strips all the exif datas before returning the image. Is it really impossible to get those datas?

Can you please help me figure out how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

I use Angular alongside ngCordova, ui-router and https://github.com/guilhermefarias/cordova-exif. So I'm taking advantage of the "resolve" feature of ui-router that has:

```
resolve: {
    picture: ['$cordovaCamera', function($cordovaCamera) {
        var options = { 
            quality : 75,
            destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            allowEdit : false,
            correctOrientation: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };
        return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options); //TODO: we need to handle errors
    }]
}
```

Then inside the corresponding controller I have

myApp.controller('UploadController', [
      '$scope',
      'picture',
      function( $scope, picture ) {

```
    //Picture
    $scope.snapShot = picture;

    CordovaExif.readData(picture, function(exifObject) {
      console.log(exifObject);
    });
```

etc..

But I get the following error 
processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
Followed by the stacktrace and an enormous string that I'm quite sure is base64 even if it doesn't work with any base64 to image decoder I tried online...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about at least of the **two** plugins:

- **lorinbeer's Cordova Exif Utility** has no Android support
- **kamilersz' cordova-plugin-exif** only has API for setting some Exif meta data and for getting Wi-Fi information from device.

But the **Cordova Exif by guilhermefarias** seems really promising and if you show the code you were trying, I might be able to help you. And of course it isn't impossible to get the Exif as it is part of the actual file. It is just the Cordova's default camera plugin that loses the Exif when selecting image from gallery. This seems to be really well done (based on code I read) and documented.

Then there is also the possibility to just read the image as binary data and apply something like [Exif.js](https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js) to read the Exif. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23218295/1744702) by user Richard Nichols on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Since I use Angularjs with ngCordova I take advantage of the resolve functionality of ui-router where I have the code you'll see on my original question above.
As far as you know is there any alternative plugin that doesn't strip out exif data?

Comment: Not that I know there exists any plugins for camera that wouldn't strip the Exif. But the Richard Nichols' answer is great to go around that. About your code for Cordova Exif, please check [this](https://github.com/guilhermefarias/cordova-exif#complete-example) for complete example which should be working.

Comment: After a bunch of tests the only solution that works is Richard Nichols' one.
As far as I can see when I'm inside entry.file(function(file) I have an object that give me the localUrl of the file, so I could also convert it to base64 and show the actual image, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you could read it as base64 and show it, that is what I am doing for my app. But how is that related to Exif?

Comment: Sorry if I've been unclear. I'm trying to show a picture with its location and date in a view.
Anyway, you're solution was definitively right about exif! Thank you very much!

Comment: @EnricoDeleo Hi, did you manage to find a solution, I have the same case, when take a photo by using cordova plugin it have no location, I'm extracting the data in my server using exif JavaScript that works for photos that was taken by iOS camera but not cordova camera photos

Answer (score 0):

**kamilersz/cordova-plugin-exif** was meant only for getting Wi-fi information from device since I made that for a sole assignment. You should use **Cordova Exif by guilhermefarias** with broader API.

Answer (score 0):

taken straight from the repo, for @Shree's pleasure

**Complete Example**
This example show how its simple get exif information of photo taken by a smartphone.

```
var options = {
    quality: 90,
    sourceType: 2,
    destinationType: 1,
};

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    CordovaExif.readData(imageURI, function(exifObject) {
        console.log(exifObject);
    });
};

function onFail(message) {
    console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
```