# How to get image's GPS location information using camera plugin?

Tags: cordova, camera, gps, cordova-plugins, exif

I using apache cordova camera plugin to get picture from camera or phone album.
And I want to get image's GPS location information through metadata(EXIF). I try some cordova plugin or javascript function, but not working.
Is camera plugin stripping the image metadata(EXIF)? Or have another way to get the GPS location information?

thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863778/cordova-3-6-how-can-i-extract-gps-exif-data-from-photo-library-in-android

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the [Geolocation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation). To get the current position use:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                     [geolocationError],
                                     [geolocationOptions]);
```

Also notice this IOS info from the [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#preferences-ios).