# Phonegap - Get Pic creationdate from EXIF-data

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to get the pic creation date from the EXIF data in phonegap.

I found this solution: 
[Phonegap / Cordova camera plugin - how to get photo's date/time stamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196252/phonegap-cordova-camera-plugin-how-to-get-photos-date-time-stamp)

```
var source = fromCamera 
       ? Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA 
       : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;

var opts = {
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    sourceType: source,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function(imageURI) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI,
                    function(entry) {
                        entry.file(function(file) {
                            EXIF.getData(file, function() {
                                var datetime = EXIF.getTag(this, "DateTimeOriginal");
                                alert(datetime);
                            });                                                

                            // do something useful....

                        }, standardErrorHandler);
                    },
                    function(e) {
                        alert('Unexpected error obtaining image file.');
                        standardErrorHandler(e);
                    });
        },
        function() {
            // nada - cancelled
        },
        opts);
```

I have tried the code from the solution but I get the error "EXIF is not defined". Is any include or plugin required? 
(Camera and FileTransfer Plugin is installed.)

Comment: you have to include the exif.js from https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js into your main html file.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Thats the missing *.js