# Extracting exif data in android (phonegap)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I think I have found the cause of the issue below.

if I run the following code:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = function (evt) {
            console.log("read success");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
```

the console logs "read success", but then nothing else. It looks like the file reader is seeing the file, but not extracting the binary data.

Original Question:

I'm working on an app, which needs to check that a photo has exif data (gps specifically) before uploading to a server. I have found through stackoverflow, that this API seems to be the best recommended:

https://github.com/guilhermefarias/cordova-exif

I have emailed the developer of that API, but not heard back, I have also tried 2 other exif api's but I'm getting the same errors.

The issue I'm getting is that the returned object is always coming back as "undefined" when I know the photo has exif (I've tested with exif viewers).

Even using the example code on the github page, returns "undefined"

```
var options = {
quality: 90,
sourceType: 2,
destinationType: 1,
};

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
CordovaExif.readData(imageURI, function(exifObject) {
    console.log(exifObject);
});
};

function onFail(message) {
console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
```

I don't see any permission errors on the console, and I have added the file + camera plugins as per the documentation.

I am aware of a 'bug' in later versions of android where the camera app returns a relative URI rather than a physical location, but I have resolved that using a gallary picker API, the the filepath is:

file:///data/data/io.cordova.ExifTest/cache/IMG_20150524_104204901336210.jpg

if I put an  in the index.html with the above URI, the image displays on the screen, so I know this URI is valid and correct.

At the moment, I'm going through the API's code, line by line trying to debug it, but I'm hoping someone out there has already had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer here:
[Phonegap / Cordova camera plugin - how to get photo's date/time stamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196252/phonegap-cordova-camera-plugin-how-to-get-photos-date-time-stamp)

I had already tried this method, but I was also still just getting "undefined" back. I figured I'd try a different tag (GPSLatitude) and it worked.