# Cordova Camera Add TimeStamp WaterMark Automatically [Android]

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I have been using this library https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera for cordova camera function.

I would like to automatically add a time-stamp watermark on capturing the image before sending it to the database.

I understand from another SO post, [Phonegap / Cordova camera plugin - how to get photo's date/time stamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196252/phonegap-cordova-camera-plugin-how-to-get-photos-date-time-stamp) , that it is possible to get the EXIF data via JavaScript and the cordova-plugin-camera allows for editImage() function.

But I would like the whole process to be automatic.

Comment: automatic for you or for the user? for you, no, it's not possible. For the user yes, if you create a function that once you get the image url and image EXIF, you edit the image to add the watermark. Or you can create a plugin that uses camera direct instead of the current plugin that uses a camera intent http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html (it's not easy)

Comment: @jcesarmobile Hi, Yes to automatic for user once they take a picture. Other then using camera direct, is there any alternatives? And do you know of any javascript which can edit image like what you said above?

Comment: As I said, if you use the cordova camera plugin, you use the getPicture function to get the image url, with the image url you get the EXIF (with the post you linked), and then you edit the image to add the watermark. You can use a canvas for image editing, not sure if there are other ways of doing this with javascript