# ionic 2 camera capture image with timestamp and lat long over image

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Any cordova plugin?

The **camera capture image with timestamp and lat long over image.**

I did not found any plugin or way to have image with timestamp and lat long stamp over image.

Comment: I also don't know of any plugin that does that. Have you tried to do it yourself in javascript? You can take a picture, load it and then add the timestamp and lat/long by using a canvas.

Comment: Nope, not tried that - I was looking for any plugin that works for both Images and Video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i checked, I could find only one plugin which matches close to your requirement.

This [image handler plugin](https://github.com/toboqus/Cordova-Plugin-Image-Handler) provides a number of methods that can be used to manipulate images with the cordova framework

Have a look at the `timestamp` function in the plugin page. It almost does what you are looking for. This function will timestamp a given image in the top left hand corner with the current system date and time.

Hope it should be helful to start off. You can also check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693021/cordova-camera-add-timestamp-watermark-automatically-android) for other possible approaches.

Comment: Ok Gandhi thanks!. I will try that. Is there any way to stamp lat long over the image and video at the time of capturing.

Comment: @AnkitMaheshwari Please accept the answer if it was helpful. Already lost out on the bounty question

Comment: Hi @AnkitMaheshwari , Can you please share me example of lat and lang over camera capture  image ?